# How do I get exception details in XCode 4.6?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception, xcode4, xcode4.6

I used to get exception details from apps running in the simulator like so:

```
po $eax
```

Ever since I upgraded to XCode 4.6 it's stopped working; I always get this error:

```
error: warning: couldn't get object pointer (substituting NULL):
Couldn't find '_cmd' with appropriate type in scope
Couldn't materialize struct: Couldn't read eax (materialize)
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression
```

I've seen people recommend using this:

```
register read eax
```

But that gives me this error:

```
eax          = error: unavailable
```

How do I get exception details in XCode 4.6?

Comment: What sort of exception are you referring to?  Objective-C or C++ or something else?

Comment: Objective-C exceptions.

Comment: And why don't you break on `objc_exception_throw` instead?

Comment: Because they have a feature called Exception Breakpoints, and I don't expect it to be worthless, particularly as it used to work fine.

Comment: I don't understand your response.

Comment: Check this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14767076/696779


Best Regards.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you break on `objc_exception_throw` the stack frame selected is the last frame in your code, before calling any libraries that might have thrown the exception. At that point lldb doesn't let you access some of the registers (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13712939/1489997) for a possible explanation.

To get the exception details you have to select the `objc_exception_throw` stack frame:

[image: Select the objc_exception_throw stack frame]

Now `po $eax` (`po $rax` if you are running on OS X 64 bit, `po $r0` on iPhone/iPad, `po $x0` on arm64) should give you the exception details.

Comment: Glad I could help. Just to clarify: Breaking on `objc_exception_throw` **is** an exception breakpoint.

Comment: It's a breakpoint, and it breaks on exceptions, but it's not the XCode feature whose name is 'Exception Breakpoint'.

Comment: So what is the difference?

Comment: I believe that the XCode one will catch other sorts of exception (e.g. C++). My question was just about objc ones, though.

Comment: You're right about C++. If you're setting it to Objective-C, on through, it breaks on `objc_exception_throw`. The only difference to setting a symbolic breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` is that in the latter case `objc_exception_throw` is selected on the call stack trace. (At least I don't know of any other difference)

Comment: I've set up a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` and added a couple of actions- `po [$rax name]` and `po [$rax reason]`. Big timesaver!

Comment: So we have $rax for 64-bit OSX, but this doesn't seem to work on 64-bit iOS devices. Any update on this for 64-bit iPad/iPhone live devices? Is "po $x0" the correct debugger command?

Comment: when I tried this (Mavericks, Xcode 5.1, Mac project) it was $rd1.

Comment: @PeterNLewis: You probably mean `$rdi`, which for me holds the same value as `$rax` when stopped at an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Yes, sorry, $rdi - but $rax did not work for me, thats when I went through the other registered.  Might have just been me, but I figured its worth noting in case someone else tries and this helps.

Comment: `error: Couldn't materialize struct: couldn't read the value of register r0
Errored out in Execute, couldn't PrepareToExecuteJITExpression`

Comment: @simon you also can’t add conditions to exception breakpoints, but you can to symbolic breakpoints, which is useful if you want to ignore certain types of exceptions by string matching the message or class.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have anything to add, just use [this awesome guide](http://qwan.org/2013/06/18/how-to-snatch-the-error-code-from-the-trap-frame-in-xcode/) that helps you setup exception breakpoint with **action (script) that prints exception description in console**.

Answer (score -3):

Go to :

```
Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run on the left -> diagnostics tab
```

and then enable zombies